# Can I use google maps navigation within my app

Tags: google-maps, android, navigation

I am considering building an app which includes google maps. The app functions by tracking the GPS location of the vehicle and showing it to the respective user on the Android app with some additional stats. I also would like to include turn by turn navigation. Based on what I have read in Google's terms and conditions it does not allow to use navigation but I have seen on the app runtastic on google play store using google maps navigation. I wanted to know how can I avail this functionality. Can it be made available to use on purchasing of the work API? Also does Google provide it's SDK for the same.

It's been a few days now that I had sent this inquiry to google but haven't received any response so decided to post it here.

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_4 / c. / iii.

> **10.4 Restrictions on Unfair Exploitation of the Service and Content.**
>
> ...
>
> ***c. Restrictions on your Maps API Implementations.***
>
> ...
>
> iii. No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

Comment: Even asset tracking requires the Enterprise 'Work API' you can work out the costs https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/?hl=en

Comment: You could always try [Mapbox Directions](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/directions/) with their [Android SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/)

Comment: Thank you for your responses. @Mapperz: My concern is that even on purchasing of the Work API will I be able to use the turn by turn navigation system of google? It is because of this I am not fully convinced if I should go ahead with google maps Work API as I want their turn by turn navigation.  I simply don't want to jump into development just to realize google does not allow navigation. I am looking into Mapbox also as a possibility if google does not provide navigation on purchase of work api.